# Why can't I upload any new pictures to my shared link on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

If I share a link to one of my business pages, Facebook automatically selects the featured image from the website page. I cannot add any new pictures from my pc to this post. Facebook always selects the featured, even if I click on the new picture.